# Did Douglas Adams get the idea of communication/alien dolphins from "Stationary Orbit" by Peter Macey?

Tags: inspiration, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams, stationary-orbit

Inspired by [this question/answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141840/a-novel-about-signals-from-aliens-that-turns-out-to-be-from-dolphins).

Given that the novel by Macey was written four years prior to the first broadcast of *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* and subsequent novelization, is there any evidence to suggest that Douglas Adams was aware of/referencing the Macey book, *Stationary Orbit*?

Pre-emptively acknowledging that this is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/what-were-some-of-douglas-adamss-hhggs-influences) (though, that is a list and this is looking for a specific answer regarding the two works).

Comment: I've never seen a direct connection. The idea of communication with cetaceans was popular beginning in the 1950's. Although it's possible, because the 'sapient cetaceans' was a trope that existed long before Macey, I'd suggest it more likely it came from the broader interest. For example, Robert Merle's 1967 novel 'Un animal doué de raison' ('A Sentient Animal' was translated into English (as 'The Day of the Dolphin') and published in 1969. The film version, 1973, starred George C. Scott. Larry Niven's Known Space and even 'The Incredible Mr. Limpet' (1964) also came out before Macey.

Comment: Who is this "Macey"?